# Pentaho Spoon Value Mapping

Tags: sql, pentaho, etl, pentaho-spoon

I am new to the spoon tool and I am extracting one table values to load another table with same attributes. In the **first table** there is a column holding **nchar** values like 'y' and 'no' which represents(yes and no).

My problem is the **second table** has a column that will hold these values as a **tinyint** like 'y' -> 1 and 'n' -> '0'

table1

- y
- y
- n
- n
- y

table2

- 1
- 1
- 0
- 0
- 1

So is there an easy way for replacing these values and changing their types by mapping them. I can do this job in my sql statement like below

```
SELECT CASE <variable> 
           WHEN <value>      THEN <returnvalue> 
           WHEN <othervalue> THEN <returnthis> 
           ELSE <returndefaultcase> 
       END 
  FROM <table>
```

If there are only 'y' and 'n' values this solution would be okay but since there are lots of values in lots of tables like ('a'->2, 'b'->3, 'c'->4) it is kind of a headache for me now.
If someone tells me a practical approach I would appreciate it.

Comment: How about introducing a mapping table which is read from the DB or e.g. a CSV file?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a mapping table? Is it something like storing all the equivalent values in a second table? @Marcus Rickert

Comment: Exactly! Although this is a bit more work than a coded mapping in ETL you can see it as an investment which may save you time later on. It depends on how quickly your mapping develops over time.

Comment: Sounds logical. I will keep that in mind. Thank you sir @Marcus Rickert

Answer (score 2):

Use the value mapper step for something so simple or just use the case statement like you have. I wouldn't store that mapping in the database since it is so simple.

In the valuemapper add a target field since the data types don't line up. Then if you want to rename or replace the old column use the select values step

[image]

Comment: As far as i know value mapper is not supporting type conversion. It would work if i want to change char to char or stn like that but i need a char -> tinyint conversion as well. So it seems that i will keep doing that case statement.. @Abercrombieande

Comment: You need to use a new field when the datatypes don't match. I edit the answer above to show this.

Comment: Ok i upvoted for now. And be sure that i will try this step on Monday and will accept your answer if it works. Thanks @Abercrombieande